# Update 50 records as efficiently as possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to update the position of 50 records at the same time.

Is it possible to use [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) to update all records (all with different new values) in one single query, or is there any other way other than looping the collection and do an [`update`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) for each and every record?

Comment: You can use `update_all` so update batch if they have the same value to update, other wise this is not what you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in both the comments and the provided documentation, the `update_all` method is there to update *all* instances of a Model:

```
#Examples
Customer.update_all wants_email: true

# Update all books with 'Rails' in their title
Book.where('title LIKE ?', '%Rails%').update_all(author: 'David')
```

As `@matanco` mentioned in the comments, this is great for cases where you need to `bulk` update with exactly the same data. However, if you want different data, you'll have to iterate through the various conditions & use `update_all` on each of them

--

**Conditional**

If you're looking to update the attributes for specific conditions, you'll need to do something like this:

```
condition1 = Model.where param: "value"
condition1.update_all(attr: "value")

condition2 = Model.where param: "value"
condition2.update_all(attr: "value")
```

Comment: So effectively, to update all 50 records with their new position (every position is unique), I would need 50 queries to the DB?